# Moment around a point in a frame

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, torque, statics, moment

**Note:** Both diagrams are 2d(they might look 3d because I drew them manually.)
I have a prismatic frame that looks like this:[image: Frame]
I made a section on the half of the first pillar(the red line represents the section), to study the internal forces in it(Normal force, shear force and moment.)
Here is a free body diagram at this section:
[image: Section]
A is a fixed support so I calculated its reactions as follows:

- $X_A= 100 KN$

  $Y_A= 200 KN$

  $M_A= 300 KN$

Note: $AB=3m$
I have also calculated the normal and the shear force at B, but I have a problem calculating the moment at B and here is why:
now let's apply the equilibrium equation of the moments at B, as:

$$\Sigma M_B=0$$

As you see there are the following moments:

- $X_A\times 3$

  $M_B$

  and at last $M_A$

I have done it like this:
$$ 3X_A + M_B - M_A = 0 $$
I just need to know what to do with $M_A$ should I multiply it with the distance $AB$ or just leave it.(I tried both cases and I think both are wrong). now can somebody till me what to do with the $M_A$?

### Edit:

I guess the diagrams are somehow misleading,(I am not good at drawing!).
The axis of moment B is the straight line perpendicular to the plane and passing through B and the same for A. Now please look at the first picture: imagine there is a force just above the red section, this force is causing the bending moment in B and the reaction moment in A. I want to calculate the internal moment B, and that's why I need the sum of moments at B.

Comment: Is $M_B$ moment of force about point A applied by a force at distance say $x$ from A ?

Comment: @rijulgupta I guess my diarams were a little misleading, please take a look at the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit with respect to correction/edit in question : 
First of all lets assume that $M_A$ is caused by force $F$ applied at distance $x$ from A, and distance from A to B is $L$.

> To calculate $M_a$
>       $xF = M_A$
>       $M_a = \sqrt[2]{x^2 + L^2} F \sin\theta$
>       $M_a =  \sqrt[2]{x^2 + L^2} F x / \sqrt[2]{x^2 + L^2}$
>       $M_a = M_A $
>       $M_a$ is moment of the force which provides moment $M_A$ about point A, about point B.

Rest of your equations look correct !

Comment: I want to calculate the moment at B, how can I acheive that without adding the $M_A$

Comment: I sense you are interested in calculating $M_B$ only, so I suggest taking the axis along AB, moment of $X_A$ is not rotating about this axis, so leave it, about this axis the moment of $M_A$ is $M_A$ only so just equate both of them for equilibrium.

Comment: Are you talking about total Moment about B ?

Comment: No the diagrams are 2d not 3d, $M_A$ is the moment around A .the reaction of A towards bending.

Comment: The total moment around B is zero since it is an internal moment, I want to calculate the bending moment around B.

Comment: Evej if the diagram is 2d, the force which are causing $M_A$ and $M_B$ afe directed inside and outside the plane, that is why they are able to give a moment, which lies in the plane, remember it is obtained by cross product, force has to be out of plane, since both radial and torque vector are in plane.

Answer (score 0):

$M_a$ is a Moment of Couple and is a free vector. it can be moved any where in space.

whereas Force(X and Y) are sliding vectors they can only be moved along their line of action (principle of transmissibility).